# Prove Polynomial Interpolation is unique

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

This question originates from Pinter's Abstract Algebra Chapter 26, Exercise H3.

Theorem 2. If $a(x)$ has distinct roots $c_1, \cdots, c_m$ in field $F$, then $(x - c_1)(x - c_2) \cdots (x - c_m)$ is a factor of $a(x)$.

Consider a commonly used technique for constructing a polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $n$
which assumes given values $b_0, b_1,\cdots, b_n$ are given points $a_0, a_1,\cdots,a_n$.
That is
\begin{align*}
    p(a_0) = b_0, p(a_1)=b_1,\cdots,p(a_n) = b_n
\end{align*}

For each $i = 0,1, \cdots, n$, let
\begin{align*}
    q_i(x) =(x - a_0)\cdots(x - a_{i-1})(x - a_{i+1}) \cdots (x - a_n)
\end{align*}
Note $q_i(a_j) = 0$ for $j \ne i$, and $q_i(a_i) \ne 0$.

Let $q_i(a_i) = c_i$, and define $p(x)$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
    p(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{b_i}{c_i}q_i(x) = \frac{b_0}{c_0}q_0(x) + \cdots + \frac{b_n}{c_n}q_n(x)
\end{align*}
Note $p(a_0) = b_0, p(a_1) = b_1,\cdots,p(a_n)=b_n$.

> Prove that there is one and only one polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $\le n$
>   such that $p(a_0) = b_0, \cdots, p(a_n) = b_n$.

Attempt:

Suppose there exists a polynomial $s(x)\ne p(x)$ with degree $\le n$ such that
$s(a_0) = b_0, \cdots, s(a_n) = b_n$ (where $a_0,\cdots,a_n$ are distinct).  Let $p(x) - s(x) = r(x)$, so 
$r(a_0) = \cdots = r(a_n) = 0$.

By Theorem 2, $(x-a_0)\cdots(x-a_n)$ is a factor of $r(x)$ which implies $r(x)$ has degree $\ge n+1$,
which is impossible. Hence $r(x)$ must be zero and $p(x) = s(x)$.

Correct?

Comment: Use [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation), also the proof has two parts, the first part that you should prove the existence and the other part that you should prove the uniqueness (using Kronecker delta would even make the proof easier)

Comment: Yes, your proof of uniqueness is correct.